# how to send empty value by html form to not change row

Tags: html, sql, forms

I am using a html form like

```
<form method ="" action="">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

lets say i will not require those all fields.now if i want to update one filed and hit submit button my php code always sending empty value to non filed form. i want to remain same (past posted) value in my sql table row.

is there any good solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not mentioned here that how you are saving data. First you need to consider whether the field can genuinely be empty or not. If the field should never be empty then you can check for empty fields when you are trying to save those data and if any field is empty then don't update that field. Just leave the previous data.

Comment: Submitting and empty value HTML form resulting to remove past data from my SQL row so I want to live it even I enter nothing in my form I hope you understand now.